# Software which writes long math expressions in short form by detecting the patterns?

Tags: real-analysis, summation, computational-mathematics, products, mathematica

Is there any software which can detects the patterns in long math expression and collects them as sums and products in short form. I am working with some long expressions of the following forms. I have longer expressions than this. I was wondering if I can shorten them in some programme to save time.

$$\left(-a_0 a_1 a_2-a_0 a_1 a_3-a_0 a_2 a_3-a_1 a_2 a_3-a_0 a_1 a_4-a_0 a_2 a_4-a_1
a_2 a_4-a_0 a_3 a_4-a_1 a_3 a_4-a_2 a_3 a_4-a_0 a_1 a_5-a_0 a_2 a_5-a_1 a_2 a_5-a_0 a_3 a_5-a_1 a_3 a_5-a_2 a_3 a_5-a_0 a_4 a_5-a_1 a_4 a_5-a_2 a_4
a_5-a_3 a_4 a_5-a_0 a_1 a_6-a_0 a_2 a_6-a_1 a_2 a_6-a_0 a_3 a_6-a_1 a_3 a_6-a_2 a_3 a_6-a_0 a_4 a_6-a_1 a_4 a_6-a_2 a_4 a_6-a_3 a_4 a_6-a_0 a_5 a_6-a_1
a_5 a_6-a_2 a_5 a_6-a_3 a_5 a_6-a_4 a_5 a_6-a_0 a_1 a_7-a_0 a_2 a_7-a_1 a_2 a_7-a_0 a_3 a_7-a_1 a_3 a_7-a_2 a_3 a_7-a_0 a_4 a_7-a_1 a_4 a_7-a_2 a_4
a_7-a_3 a_4 a_7-a_0 a_5 a_7-a_1 a_5 a_7-a_2 a_5 a_7-a_3 a_5 a_7-a_4 a_5 a_7-a_0 a_6 a_7-a_1 a_6 a_7-a_2 a_6 a_7-a_3 a_6 a_7-a_4 a_6 a_7-a_5 a_6 a_7-a_0
a_1 a_8-a_0 a_2 a_8-a_1 a_2 a_8-a_0 a_3 a_8-a_1 a_3 a_8-a_2 a_3 a_8-a_0 a_4 a_8-a_1 a_4 a_8-a_2 a_4 a_8-a_3 a_4 a_8-a_0 a_5 a_8-a_1 a_5 a_8-a_2 a_5
a_8-a_3 a_5 a_8-a_4 a_5 a_8-a_0 a_6 a_8-a_1 a_6 a_8-a_2 a_6 a_8-a_3 a_6 a_8-a_4 a_6 a_8-a_5 a_6 a_8-a_0 a_7 a_8-a_1 a_7 a_8-a_2 a_7 a_8-a_3 a_7 a_8-a_4
a_7 a_8-a_5 a_7 a_8-a_6 a_7 a_8-a_0 a_1 a_9-a_0 a_2 a_9-a_1 a_2 a_9-a_0 a_3 a_9-a_1 a_3 a_9-a_2 a_3 a_9-a_0 a_4 a_9-a_1 a_4 a_9-a_2 a_4 a_9-a_3 a_4
a_9-a_0 a_5 a_9-a_1 a_5 a_9-a_2 a_5 a_9-a_3 a_5 a_9-a_4 a_5 a_9-a_0 a_6 a_9-a_1 a_6 a_9-a_2 a_6 a_9-a_3 a_6 a_9-a_4 a_6 a_9-a_5 a_6 a_9-a_0 a_7 a_9-a_1
a_7 a_9-a_2 a_7 a_9-a_3 a_7 a_9-a_4 a_7 a_9-a_5 a_7 a_9-a_6 a_7 a_9-a_0 a_8 a_9-a_1 a_8 a_9-a_2 a_8 a_9-a_3 a_8 a_9-a_4 a_8 a_9-a_5 a_8 a_9-a_6 a_8
a_9-a_7 a_8 a_9\right)$$

EDIT: 
$$\left(a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3+a_0 a_1 a_2 a_4+a_0 a_1 a_3 a_4+a_0 a_2 a_3 a_4+a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4+a_0 a_1 a_2 a_5+a_0
a_1 a_3 a_5+a_0 a_2 a_3 a_5+a_1 a_2 a_3 a_5+a_0 a_1 a_4 a_5+a_0 a_2 a_4 a_5+a_1 a_2 a_4 a_5+a_0 a_3 a_4 a_5+a_1 a_3 a_4 a_5+a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5+a_0 a_1
a_2 a_6+a_0 a_1 a_3 a_6+a_0 a_2 a_3 a_6+a_1 a_2 a_3 a_6+a_0 a_1 a_4 a_6+a_0 a_2 a_4 a_6+a_1 a_2 a_4 a_6+a_0 a_3 a_4 a_6+a_1 a_3 a_4 a_6+a_2 a_3 a_4
a_6+a_0 a_1 a_5 a_6+a_0 a_2 a_5 a_6+a_1 a_2 a_5 a_6+a_0 a_3 a_5 a_6+a_1 a_3 a_5 a_6+a_2 a_3 a_5 a_6+a_0 a_4 a_5 a_6+a_1 a_4 a_5 a_6+a_2 a_4 a_5 a_6+a_3
a_4 a_5 a_6+a_0 a_1 a_2 a_7+a_0 a_1 a_3 a_7+a_0 a_2 a_3 a_7+a_1 a_2 a_3 a_7+a_0 a_1 a_4 a_7+a_0 a_2 a_4 a_7+a_1 a_2 a_4 a_7+a_0 a_3 a_4 a_7+a_1 a_3
a_4 a_7+a_2 a_3 a_4 a_7+a_0 a_1 a_5 a_7+a_0 a_2 a_5 a_7+a_1 a_2 a_5 a_7+a_0 a_3 a_5 a_7+a_1 a_3 a_5 a_7+a_2 a_3 a_5 a_7+a_0 a_4 a_5 a_7+a_1 a_4 a_5
a_7+a_2 a_4 a_5 a_7+a_3 a_4 a_5 a_7+a_0 a_1 a_6 a_7+a_0 a_2 a_6 a_7+a_1 a_2 a_6 a_7+a_0 a_3 a_6 a_7+a_1 a_3 a_6 a_7+a_2 a_3 a_6 a_7+a_0 a_4 a_6 a_7+a_1
a_4 a_6 a_7+a_2 a_4 a_6 a_7+a_3 a_4 a_6 a_7+a_0 a_5 a_6 a_7+a_1 a_5 a_6 a_7+a_2 a_5 a_6 a_7+a_3 a_5 a_6 a_7+a_4 a_5 a_6 a_7+a_0 a_1 a_2 a_8+a_0 a_1
a_3 a_8+a_0 a_2 a_3 a_8+a_1 a_2 a_3 a_8+a_0 a_1 a_4 a_8+a_0 a_2 a_4 a_8+a_1 a_2 a_4 a_8+a_0 a_3 a_4 a_8+a_1 a_3 a_4 a_8+a_2 a_3 a_4 a_8+a_0 a_1 a_5
a_8+a_0 a_2 a_5 a_8+a_1 a_2 a_5 a_8+a_0 a_3 a_5 a_8+a_1 a_3 a_5 a_8+a_2 a_3 a_5 a_8+a_0 a_4 a_5 a_8+a_1 a_4 a_5 a_8+a_2 a_4 a_5 a_8+a_3 a_4 a_5 a_8+a_0
a_1 a_6 a_8+a_0 a_2 a_6 a_8+a_1 a_2 a_6 a_8+a_0 a_3 a_6 a_8+a_1 a_3 a_6 a_8+a_2 a_3 a_6 a_8+a_0 a_4 a_6 a_8+a_1 a_4 a_6 a_8+a_2 a_4 a_6 a_8+a_3 a_4
a_6 a_8+a_0 a_5 a_6 a_8+a_1 a_5 a_6 a_8+a_2 a_5 a_6 a_8+a_3 a_5 a_6 a_8+a_4 a_5 a_6 a_8+a_0 a_1 a_7 a_8+a_0 a_2 a_7 a_8+a_1 a_2 a_7 a_8+a_0 a_3 a_7
a_8+a_1 a_3 a_7 a_8+a_2 a_3 a_7 a_8+a_0 a_4 a_7 a_8+a_1 a_4 a_7 a_8+a_2 a_4 a_7 a_8+a_3 a_4 a_7 a_8+a_0 a_5 a_7 a_8+a_1 a_5 a_7 a_8+a_2 a_5 a_7 a_8+a_3
a_5 a_7 a_8+a_4 a_5 a_7 a_8+a_0 a_6 a_7 a_8+a_1 a_6 a_7 a_8+a_2 a_6 a_7 a_8+a_3 a_6 a_7 a_8+a_4 a_6 a_7 a_8+a_5 a_6 a_7 a_8+a_0 a_1 a_2 a_9+a_0 a_1
a_3 a_9+a_0 a_2 a_3 a_9+a_1 a_2 a_3 a_9+a_0 a_1 a_4 a_9+a_0 a_2 a_4 a_9+a_1 a_2 a_4 a_9+a_0 a_3 a_4 a_9+a_1 a_3 a_4 a_9+a_2 a_3 a_4 a_9+a_0 a_1 a_5
a_9+a_0 a_2 a_5 a_9+a_1 a_2 a_5 a_9+a_0 a_3 a_5 a_9+a_1 a_3 a_5 a_9+a_2 a_3 a_5 a_9+a_0 a_4 a_5 a_9+a_1 a_4 a_5 a_9+a_2 a_4 a_5 a_9+a_3 a_4 a_5 a_9+a_0
a_1 a_6 a_9+a_0 a_2 a_6 a_9+a_1 a_2 a_6 a_9+a_0 a_3 a_6 a_9+a_1 a_3 a_6 a_9+a_2 a_3 a_6 a_9+a_0 a_4 a_6 a_9+a_1 a_4 a_6 a_9+a_2 a_4 a_6 a_9+a_3 a_4
a_6 a_9+a_0 a_5 a_6 a_9+a_1 a_5 a_6 a_9+a_2 a_5 a_6 a_9+a_3 a_5 a_6 a_9+a_4 a_5 a_6 a_9+a_0 a_1 a_7 a_9+a_0 a_2 a_7 a_9+a_1 a_2 a_7 a_9+a_0 a_3 a_7
a_9+a_1 a_3 a_7 a_9+a_2 a_3 a_7 a_9+a_0 a_4 a_7 a_9+a_1 a_4 a_7 a_9+a_2 a_4 a_7 a_9+a_3 a_4 a_7 a_9+a_0 a_5 a_7 a_9+a_1 a_5 a_7 a_9+a_2 a_5 a_7 a_9+a_3
a_5 a_7 a_9+a_4 a_5 a_7 a_9+a_0 a_6 a_7 a_9+a_1 a_6 a_7 a_9+a_2 a_6 a_7 a_9+a_3 a_6 a_7 a_9+a_4 a_6 a_7 a_9+a_5 a_6 a_7 a_9+a_0 a_1 a_8 a_9+a_0 a_2
a_8 a_9+a_1 a_2 a_8 a_9+a_0 a_3 a_8 a_9+a_1 a_3 a_8 a_9+a_2 a_3 a_8 a_9+a_0 a_4 a_8 a_9+a_1 a_4 a_8 a_9+a_2 a_4 a_8 a_9+a_3 a_4 a_8 a_9+a_0 a_5 a_8
a_9+a_1 a_5 a_8 a_9+a_2 a_5 a_8 a_9+a_3 a_5 a_8 a_9+a_4 a_5 a_8 a_9+a_0 a_6 a_8 a_9+a_1 a_6 a_8 a_9+a_2 a_6 a_8 a_9+a_3 a_6 a_8 a_9+a_4 a_6 a_8 a_9+a_5
a_6 a_8 a_9+a_0 a_7 a_8 a_9+a_1 a_7 a_8 a_9+a_2 a_7 a_8 a_9+a_3 a_7 a_8 a_9+a_4 a_7 a_8 a_9+a_5 a_7 a_8 a_9+a_6 a_7 a_8 a_9\right)$$

Comment: Save time for what exactly?

Comment: Are you talking about computation time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem software can presently solve. Incidentally, your expression is $\binom{10}{3}=120$ terms, $-\sum_{ijk}a_ia_ja_k$ with the sum over size-$3$ sets $\{i,\,j,\,k\}\subseteq\{0,\,\cdots,\,9\}$.

Comment: More succinctly: $-\sum_{0\le i<j<k\le 9}a_ia_ja_k$. (And I agree with your assessment of current software capabilities.)

Comment: @TonyK Or $[x^7]\prod_{i=0}^9(x-a_i)$.

Comment: @J.G. What does  [x^7] mean? The second way you have written it, will contain $x$?

Comment: @TonyK I have added one more expression in my OP. So I can write it in your way $\sum_{0\le i<j<k<l\le 9} a_ia_ja_ka_l$?

Comment: @mathisgood $[x^n]f(x)$ is the $x^n$ coefficient in $f$.

Comment: @mathisgood: I expect you can. But I'm not going to check it!